# Process To Update Single CS File in Plugin Assembly

Tags: c#, deployment, solution

I have a .CS file that I made one small change to in Visual Studio Community 2019. I am very confused about how to get the file up to my solution in Microsoft Dynamics 365. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

I have tried the Plugin Registration Tool but clicking "Register" does nothing.

Thanks,

Josh!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial from Microsoft on updating an existing plugin (Specifically you should look at the "Update the plug-in assembly registration" section):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/tutorial-update-plug-in

You need to:
- Right click on the plugin assembly within the registration tool and select Update
- In the resulting dialogue, browse for your compiled plugin assembly dll
- Select the top check box to select all plugins and workflow activities
- Press Update Selected Plugins at the bottom

Comment: Zach, thank you for your answer. When I click "Update" nothing come up.

Comment: It sounds like your plugin registration tool is corrupted somehow. Maybe try re-installing?